# Добавление своего типа данных ( С++ )

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток, кто-нибудь подскажите что прочитать, чтобы понять, как реализовать свой тип ( речь не об ООП ). 
Пример простой. С C/C++ есть например ключевое слово int. И запись

int a = 40;

говорит компилятору: "Выдели 4 байта памяти, назови их "а" и занусь туда двоичное представление числа 40"

за счет чего я могу сделать такое слово ( не ООП ).

type a = 40;

"Выдели 8 байт (например 8) памяти, назови их "а" и засунь туда двоичное представление числа 40"

Проще говоря, кто знает где прочитать как писался Си или C++. Понимаю что это низкоуровневое и тд. Но я даже в таком ключе не могу найти информацию.

Comment: Свои типы - структуры.

Comment: Странный вопрос. Если речь не об ООП - то единственный путь править исходники C. Только какой смысл это делать, если в C представлены все типы данных, работа с которыми быстро и однозначно преобразуется в команды процессора. Все остальные типы строятся на основе этих базовых. Нет смысла что то расширять, ели это не будет поддержано процессором

Comment: Почему в заголовке `С++`, а в тегах и описании также `С` присутствует?

Comment: Если вы решили писать собственный _компилируемый_ язык, то начните с досконального изучения ассемблеров основных видов процессоров. Т.е. архитектуры intel x86, mips, arm. Думаю этих трех будет достаточно, для общего понимания 'а как оно бывает'

Answer (score 5):

Определенные пользователем типы - это  только классы и объединения.

Поэтому если вы хотите иметь запись вида

```
type a = 40;
```

то вам следует `type` определить, например, как класс

```
struct type
{
    type( int x = 0 ) : x( x ) {}
    int x;
};
```

Это возможно только в C++.

Чем отличается определенный пользователем тип от стандартных типов, предоставляемых языком? Это их поведение!

Язык C не позволяет пользователям определять собственные типы, то есть вводить новые типы с отличным от уже определенных в языке поведением.
То есть вы не можете вводить собственные спецификаторы типов и/или менять поведение уже предопределенных в языке типов.

Имейте в виду, что, например, использование спецификатора `typedef`  не определяет новый тип. Он лишь вводит алиас для существующих типов.

Вы сами в своем вопросе упомянули **ключевое** слово. Новые ключевые слова в язык вводятся только решением комитетов по стандарту языка C. Например, в С 99 было введено новое ключевое слово `_Bool` , обозначающее новый целочисленный тип.

А, например, до принятия стандарта C в языке не было ключевого слова `void`, которое предложил Страуструп.

Вы можете написать свое предложение по изменению стандарта C и послать его в комитет по стандартизации.

Если вам просто нужно иметь 8-байтовое целое число, то вы можете использовать типы `long long int`, `long long unsigned int` или типы, определенные в заголовке `<stdint.h>`.

Comment: Спасибо, очень содержательно, но я пишу свой язык, просто интересно как это и тд. Определение своих типов через обертки над существующими базовыми мне не очень импанирует. Так как на низах это делается, в том же си. Просто информацию.

Comment: @shotInLeg Посетите этот сайт https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/ Может быть найдете для себя что-нибудь полезное.

Comment: Про пользовательские типы, имхо, надо переформулировать. Т.к. структуры, объединения, перечисления, массивы, функции и т.д. это уже разные типы, которые может строить пользователь. Акцент, вероятно, стоило сделать именно на невозможности *перегрузки* операторов для пользовательских типов.

Comment: @alexolut Вопрос не о разных типах, а о том, что пользователи не могут определять поведение своих типов. Вы не можете, например, определить оператор присваивания для массивов. Все эти типы имеют предопределенное поведение, а потому не являются определенными пользователями типами. Все эти типы определены в стандарте языка.

Comment: Я понимаю. Речь именно о *переформулировке* фразы `Язык C не позволяет пользователям определять собственные типы...` т.к. она запутывает. Я бы построил иначе, например так: `Язык C не позволяет менять поведение для пользовательких типов, из-за отсутствия перегрузки операторов`.

Comment: @alexolut Перегшрузка - это частный случай ООП. Есть, например, еще интерфейсы.

Comment: Перегрузка может быть как внешняя функция, не ООП кроме того, что обращается к элементам структур.